# I want my android app to recognize finger snap sound, Is there any way?

Tags: sound-recognition

I am creating a android application and I want my application to recognize sound and find whether it is finger snap sound or not, how to do it. Is there any API available help me with it.

Comment: Did you find your answer? I'm looking for something very similar

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to write an algorithm that compares hundreds of finger snaps to compare to the microphone input, you may be better off using a voice recognition api for voice commands instead as the finger snap is very akin to other sounds.

As far as I am aware there are no APIs for a finger snap however there is audio comparing software that could help.